# Disable & Specify default selection for Html.DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

i am working on an asp.net mvc web application, inside the action method i define the following select list:-

```
ViewBag.ApproverID = new SelectList(db.staffs.ToList(), "ApproverID", "Name");
```

Then on the view i am trying to disable the dropdownlist as follow:-

```
@Html.DropDownList("ApproverID",String.Empty,new { @disabled = "disabled" } )
```

but seems the dropdownlist does not allow this and will raise syntax error on the view?can anyone adivce ?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your using the wrong overload of `DropDownList`. It would need to be

```
@Html.DropDownList("ApproverID", null, string.Empty, new { disabled= "disabled" })
```

However you should be using strongly typed helpers and binding to a model property so it can be bound on postback

Model

```
public int ApproverID { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
ViewBag.ApproverList = new SelectList(db.staffs.ToList(), "ApproverID", "Name");
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ApproverID, (SelectList)ViewBag.ApproverList, "-Please select-", new { disabled = "disabled" })
```

If you set the value of property `ApproverID` in the controller and it matches one of the values of the options it will be selected.

But why disable a dropdownlist? - You obviously cant select anything and it wont post back so the model property will be null (and probably result in a `ModelState` error). If you are just wanting to display the value, use `@Html.DisplayFor()` and `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ApproverID)` so the value posts back

Comment: i do not use strongly type DropDownListFor since the dropdownlist generated by the scaffolding template uses Html.DropDownList and not the strongly typed one,, so as i base my code the scaffolding template i try to be compatible with it ,,,,and ofcourse using the strongly typed will be more accurate.. second question on this "@Html.DropDownList("ApproverID", null, string.Empty, new { disabled= "disabled" })" overload method what does the null represents ?

Comment: What you were using was [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470329(v=vs.118).aspx) where the second parameter is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` but you were passing it a string (hence the error). What you meant (I think) was [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492256(v=vs.118).aspx) where the the 3rd parameter is the option label.

Comment: also i am using dropdown list instead of displayfor, because the field will show a username (Approver user name) while i will be storing the userID ,, so if i use Displayfor with hidden field i will be posting the username,,,so i have to query the DB  to get the userid based on the username ,, while using dropdownlist will provide the ability to show a value , while submitting another value ..

Comment: I strongly recommend using `DropDownListFor()` but if you do use `DropDownList()`, then still bind to a property with `@Html.DropDownList("ApproverID", (SelectList)ViewBag.ApproverList, string.Empty, new { disabled= "disabled" })`. But as a noted, its all a bit pointless doing this and then disabling the `<select>` since disabled controls do not post back.

Comment: You don't really need to do that. Just get the username associated with the  ApproverID, assign it to a view model property or a `ViewBag` property and display it in the view (along with `HiddenFor()` so you post back the `ApproverID` (and you can always style the display element to look look a `select` tag if that's what you want)

Comment: now if i write this "@Html.DropDownList("ApproverID", null, string.Empty, new { disabled= "disabled" })" so this means that i am specifying null for the selectlist,, but still mvc will be build the selectlist based on the passed viewbag is this correct?

Comment: I believe so, but only if "ApproverID" is a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (which `SelectList` is) - I would never do it that way so you will need to test it